# SQLite joining tables with no direct relation

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Im having problems figuring out how to select data from one table which is connected to another table in two different ways. Here is an image of my database model:
[image]

The table i want to select from is the project table. I want to get all projects connected to a given user.

A user can be directly part of a project, without beeing part of a group. So in this case the connection from user to project is made through the project_participants table.
But now.. lets say the user is part of a group, and this group is connected to a project through the group_project table. Now how do i get this project to show up in my result?

The SQL statement i have to far is able to get the projects which is directly connected to a user. The statement looks like:

```
Cursor c = database
            .rawQuery(
                    "SELECT p.*, pt.deadline FROM "
                            + project_table
                            + " p JOIN project_task pt "
                            + "ON pt.project_id_foreign = p._id "
                            + " JOIN "
                            + project_participants_table
                            + " pp "
                            + "ON pp.project_id_foreign = p._id AND pp.user_id_foreign = ? "
                            //+ "JOIN "
                            //+ group_project_table
                            //+ " gp ON //gp.project_id_foreign = p._id "
                            //+ "AND EXISTS(SELECT group_id_foreign "
                            //+ "FROM group_participants "
                            //+ "WHERE user_id_foreign = ?) ",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(userId) });
```

The lines i commented out is the JOIN im trying to get to work.
So, how can i get all standalone projects and group projects for a given user in the same query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do an UNION with the query that gets the projects that the user is in:

```
SELECT p.*, pt.deadline 
FROM project_table p 
INNER JOIN project_task pt 
   ON pt.project_id_foreign = p._id
INNER JOIN project_participants_table pp 
   ON pp.project_id_foreign = p._id AND pp.user_id_foreign = ? 
UNION
SELECT p.*, pt.deadline 
FROM project_table p 
INNER JOIN project_task pt 
   ON pt.project_id_foreign = p._id
INNER JOIN group_project gp
   ON gp.project_id_foreign = p._id
INNER JOIN groups g
   ON gp.group_id = g._id
INNER JOIN group_participants gps
   ON gps.group_id_foreign = g._id
WHERE gps.user_id_foreign = ?
```

This will get the the projects the user is in from both paths, but because UNION doesn't return duplicate values from both parts of the UNION, if he is in a project by himself and as part of a group, the query only returns one result.